# attaching text file to Gmall app not working on Android 11

Tags: android, file

I found out that I am unable to attach a file to a mail client that I'm opening from my app on Android 11.
It might be related to the storage access changes in Android 11, but I'm not sure how I need to adjust the code for it to be supported.
I store privately a log file with in external cache dir.

My intent is :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("abc@gmail.com"))
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, logFile)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.type = type
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email via::"))
    return true
}
```

and the file is :

```
 val logFile = File(ctx.externalCacheDir, "MyLogFile.log")
```

**Solution with FileProvider which didn't work :**

I changed this line :

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, logFile)
```

into this :

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider", logFile))
```

and manifest :

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

and provider_paths :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path name="MyLogFile" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: `but it throws IllegalArgumentException` On which line? And i asked you to post complete log in extra block.

Comment: Please remove some comments.

Comment: `intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` And remove that line.

Comment: I added the exception to bottom of the post, and regarding the "parse(mailto)" it doesn't even reach there, it crashes on `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriFromFile....)`

Comment: /data/data/.... is not external cache but internal.

Comment: ok , I accidentally left `ctx.cacheDir` instead of `ctx.externalCacheDir` when I tried something. Anyway, now the exception doesn't happen - but it doesn't attach the file.
and if I remove the line `Uri.parse("mailto:")` - then `resolveActivity` returns null

Comment: @BVtp did dyou solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved with replacing:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
```

with

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("mime/type");
```

and in manifest:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: are you sure you're targeting sdk 30 (android 11) ?
it doesn't work for me

Comment: ohh yes, i receveid error on attaching, after this fix it works. Can you share your code?

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: BTW, I found this blog post (at the bottom) that suggests that SENDTO does not support attachments.  https://cketti.de/2016/01/08/sending-email-using-intents/